# Django Country State City Chained Dropdown

Tags: django, django-filter

**Configuration:** I have created 2 apps csc and members. **CSC:** contains country, state, city and **Users** contains a custom user model. The users model using foreign keys to access country, state and city from CSC app. The CSC database contains all the countries, states, cities. And i am displaying user list in fronend and also an option to filter the content by country, state, city by django-filter. I am using django smart_selects to chain them in admin.

**Question:** I wanted to show only those countries, states and cities, which has the members not all my country database. and also i wanted to link those 3 dropdowns.

**CSC - Models.py**

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Country'), max_length=255, null=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(_('Code'), max_length=10, null=True)
    iso_code_short = models.CharField(_('ISO Code Short'), max_length=2, null=True)
    iso_code_long = models.CharField(_('ISO Code Long'), max_length=3, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class State(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('State'), max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name


class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = ChainedForeignKey('State', chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=255, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**Members - models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    state = ChainedForeignKey(State, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, null=True, blank=True)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field="state", chained_model_field="state", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, null=True, blank=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

**filter.py**

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    country = CharFilter(label=_('Country'), field_name='country__name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    state = CharFilter(label=_('State'), field_name='state__name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    city = CharFilter(label=_('City'), field_name='city__name', lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['country', 'state', 'city']
```

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Have a read through of: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

Comment: Yes I have gone through that excellent tutorial. But i need that using django-filter.

Comment: what do you mean by 'link those 3 dropdowns"?

Comment: @AMG i wanted to use those country, state and city.. in the django template to filter the content.. so when i select a particular country, then the respective states should show there.. and same for city..